# How to use Siri to play a specific song on YouTube?

Tags: itunes, youtube, ios

For example, I want to be able to tell Siri, "Play Aladdin a whole new world." Then, YouTube should start playing [Aladdin - A Whole New World](https://youtu.be/sVxUUotm1P4) in the background, just as the Music app does when I tell Siri to play a song from my iTunes Library. Note: I have YouTube Red.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. [According to sources](https://9to5mac.com/2016/06/14/how-siri-works-in-ios-10-for-third-party-apps-rich-integration-with-six-kinds-of-application/), Apple only (currently) allows third-party developers to access Siri APIs for the following functions:

> For iOS 10.0, the Siri API will only work with six kinds of
>   application: ride booking (think Uber), messaging, Photo Search (find
>   photos and videos in a particular app), payments (‘Send $100 to John
>   with SquareCash’), VoIP Calling (e.g: Skype) and Workouts (for
>   starting health and fitness activities).

You could probably use OK Google or whatever it's called. Never used it myself, but as YouTube is owned by Google I'd be surprised if there wasn't some integration between the two.